# Reporting instances

Tags: reporting-services

Currently I am trying to work with reporting service instances through local network.
But the problem is, I am using WMI provider for getting reporting service instances from other machine in local network, I am getting access denied exception.
Do you guys have any ideas how can I actually return all reporting service instances in local network, maybe without using WMI if it is possible?

Thanks, looking for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

You need to the have the local admin of the SSRS Server go in and add users to be a 'browser'.  By default SSRS is set up with only the local admin who installed the SSRS Server instance as the only one able to view the site.  You need to go onto that server, log in, go into the 
'Reporting Service Configuration Manager', Should display your 'ReportServer' instance if properly set up.  Click OK, Click the 'Report Manager URL' on the left side, go to the link displayed.  The default is usually like 'http: //(servername)/Reports'.

Once in you typically click 'site settings' on the upper right in SQL 2008 and higher.  Click Security, add user or group as a 'System User'.  Next go back to the 'home' landing page.  Click 'Folder Settings', Security do the same thing except for 'Browser' if you want them to see reports.  If you cannot get to this main landing page from the local user that installed you have other issues and need to first determine that an admin can log on.  This should be the first step of administering SSRS, is verifying the default admin can log in and see the site and the web service.